# What is the purpose of collecting souls in Soulcraft?

Tags: soulcraft

That is an incredibly dumb question, however I didn't find the answer!

Comment: I take it you don't need them for crafting?  That seems kind of odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It is a "minor" currency, which can buy some items, as opposed to "gold" currency, which can buy all.